# Do all burr grinders statically-charge the grinds?

Tags: equipment, grinder

Do all burr grinders statically-electrically–charge the grinds, or do only the faster-operating ones do this?

Krups GVX212 burr grinders [are notorious](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B0001I9R8W/#reviews-image-gallery-container) for producing statically-charged grinds that stick to the plastic hopper:

[image]
[image]

Do all electric burr grinders produce statically-charged grinds, or does it depend upon the grind speed* or other factors?

<sup>*The Krups GVX212 does 20g in ~30 seconds.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "Different grinders, coffees, and environments may produce more or less static" ("[Reducing Static in your Grinder](https://clivecoffee.com/blogs/learn/reducing-static-in-your-grinder)").

According to "[Stop Coffee Grinder Static with RDT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CAgWc-RW8XU)," "you'll get more static during the drier months or with darker roasted and therefore drier beans".

The "[Ross Droplet Technique (RDT)](https://www.home-barista.com/grinders/ross-droplet-technique-eliminating-grinder-static-t24051.html)" was pioneered in 2005. Basically, you stir the beans in or spray them with a small amount of water, immediately before grinding. The water reduces static but does not clog the grinder.

Coffee grinds are insulators. There are several methods of discharging insulators ([Assis](https://www.ifi.unicamp.br/%7Eassis/), [*Experimental and Historical Foundations of Electricity* vol. 1](https://www.ifi.unicamp.br/%7Eassis/Electricity.pdf), §7.14 "How to Discharge an Electrified Insulator?"):

1. Wait. The insulator will discharge over time. ([*ibid.*](https://www.ifi.unicamp.br/%7Eassis/Electricity.pdf) Experiment 7.29)
2. Submerse the insulator in water. ([*ibid.*](https://www.ifi.unicamp.br/%7Eassis/Electricity.pdf) Experiment 7.30)
3. Hold a flame near the insulator. ([*ibid.*](https://www.ifi.unicamp.br/%7Eassis/Electricity.pdf) Experiment 7.31, first discovered by the physicist [William Gilbert](https://www.encyclopedia.com/people/medicine/medicine-biographies/william-gilbert), 1544-1603)

Comment: when i had a grinder like this, i glued an aluminium strip inside wrapped to the outside and touched it to discharge static.

Comment: @ths That discharged all the grains?

Comment: it helped quite a lot. of course the grinds need to be in contact with the strip to work.

Comment: @ths I tried that, and it didn't reduce the static, even for the grains in direct contact with the aluminum foil.